# Combining koa-passport with koa-router (getting user data)

Tags: mongodb, passport.js, koa

I have created a login which is able to login a user and store the user if they are new in the database.

The user is then redirected to `/` and then is checked if they are authenticated or not, see below (app.js):

```
.get('/', function* () {
    if (this.isAuthenticated()) {
        yield this.render('homeSecure', {}); // <-- need user data here
    } else {
        yield this.render('homePublic', {});
    }
```

As I commented in the code, I would like to send the user object of which is logged in. I have no idea how to get a hold of the id of the person logged in as the documentation for koa in general is not as complete as that of express.

I am using `koa-generic-session-mongo` to handle my sessions. Here is my GoogleStrategy (auth.js):

```
var user = null;
// ...
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google').Strategy;
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        returnURL: 'http://localhost:' + (process.env.PORT || 3000) + '/auth/google/callback',
        realm: 'http://localhost:' + (process.env.PORT || 3000)
    },
    function (identifier, profile, done) {
        var emails = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < profile.emails.length; i++) {
            emails.push(profile.emails[i].value);
        }
        co(function* () {
            yield users.findOne({
                emails: emails
            });
        });
        if (user === null) { // first time signin, create account
            co(function* () {
                user = {
                    id: 1,
                    name: profile.displayName,
                    emails: emails
                };
                yield users.insert(user);
            });
        }
        console.log(user);
        done(null, user);
    }));
```

Comment: where does `user` variable get its value before the `if (user === null)` check, I don't get it

Comment: @3k `user` is a global, I'll update the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
publicRouter
    .get('/', function* () {
        if (this.isAuthenticated()) {
            yield this.render('homeSecure', {
                user: this.req.user
            });
        } else {
            yield this.render('homePublic', {});
        }
    })...
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me out a lot. For some reason the user object ends up in the node context `this.req.user` and not just in `this.user` or `this.request.user` (both of which are the Koa context objects that I thought would be used). Does anyone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I've not used koa-passport, I've just looked at the code.*

According to [the source code of the koa-passport library](https://github.com/rkusa/koa-passport/blob/master/lib/framework/koa.js#L25-L38), the property you're looking for is `passport.user`, and is used like so:

```
app.use( function*(){
    var user = this.passport.user
})
```

Thus, your code sample would become

```
.get('/', function* () {
    if (this.isAuthenticated()) {
        yield this.render('homeSecure', this.passport.user );
    } else {
        yield this.render('homePublic', {});
    }
```

If that does not work, [this file](https://github.com/rkusa/koa-passport/blob/master/lib/framework/request.js) leads me to suspect that koa-passport follows the standard passport interface and provides `this.user` to the request.